# Searching history using opengrok

Tags: opengrok

I have been working on OPENGROK for searching through my SVN code repository. It requires a checked out version of the repository to index it.

I have been able to achieve is searching through the repository when I have checked out version on my system. Where I am stuck is when I try to search through the history of the repository. What can I do?

Also, how can I update the indexes instead of creating new ones all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of opengrok are you using ? There are two ways opengrok can show history information

1. If opengrok and subversion are installed on the same local server OR
2. If you have opengrok version > 0.7, history from a remote svn can be fetched as well.

Reference:

```
Note: A local CVSROOT (or SVN if opengrok version less than 0.7) repository must be available. File history will not be fetched from a remote server for CVS (& SVN if opengrok version less than 0.7) !.
```

https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-install-OpenGrok

Update 1: One more thing to verify

The shell script "OpenGrok" in the bin directory would have an option called "OPENGROK_REMOTE_REPOS_OFF". Check that it should be blank in the script.

Comment: I have opengrok 0.11. OpenGrok and SVN are not installed on same server. They are installed on different server. Can you please tell me how to enable history for something like this. The link you have added is not that helpful as i already tried the same but it didn't work.

Comment: What a complicate thing it is to setup SVN with OpenGrok... Why on Earth would that Remote Repo be disabled by default...

Comment: @SkippyFastol : It takes extremely long to get remote subversion history. I am trying to see if there is any other optimal way to limit the amount of history that should be fetched.

Comment: Would be nice if there was some way to mirror or sync svn history