# Can not get history and Annotate works on opengrok

Tags: svn, tfs, opengrok

I just follow the steps here:
http://www.hierax.org/2009/10/opengrok-on-ubuntu-w-tomcat6.html
And get opengrok works with index searching but history and annotate did not work.

Specifically, when viewing a file, the "Home", "History", "Annotate", "Line #", etc., buttons are present in the ribbon above the displayed source file, most are links that do what they say, but History and Annotate are not links.

When I click on the folder name to display a list of files, each file has tiny H-A-D links, where H and A stand for history and annotate, respectively.  This time they are links (for example, "A" augments the URL with a=true), but when I click on it, the file is displayed without any annotation.

This can happen both with SVN and with TFS.

It can happen that in the same opengrok installation, it is possible that only some files are so affected  (this was observed with a TFS only installation).

Here is my command for generating the configuration.xml

sudo java -jar /var/lib/opengrok/bin/opengrok.jar -W /var/lib/opengrok/configuration.xml -c /usr/bin/ctages -P -S -v -s /var/lib/opengrok/src/ -d /var/lib/opengrok/data -w opengrok -L polished -r on

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. When you say that your command doesn't work, what you you mean? What result do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: The history and annotate link wasn't activated. I just want to know how to activate the history and annotate link.

Comment: Trying getting help from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084204/searching-history-using-opengrok

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

In my setup, history and annotate works when I view the file located via searching a specific branch.  When the same file is viewed from within a bundle of branches, history and annotate aren't available.

I am not sure whether this is a setup problem or an inherent limitation of bundles.